# Best practice for a button with image and text in mobile website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

Refer to the screenshot below, I have created a `div` to wrap another two `div` of image and text, then I use CSS `position: absolute` to make these `div` merge together.

However, I found that the button is not sensitive while testing on mobile devices, sometime I need to touch the button few time to take effect.

So, is there something wrong for my code and what is the best practice to create a button with image and text?

Thanks

[image]

```
<div class="r">
    <div class="a">
        <div class="i"><img src="store_btn_on.png" /></div>
        <div class="t">Shatin</div>
    </div>
    <div class="b">
        <div class="i"><img src="store_btn_off.png" /></div>
        <div class="t">Causeway Bay</div>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
        <div class="i"><img src="store_btn_off.png" /></div>
        <div class="t">Kowloon Bay</div>                            
    </div>
</div>
```

**Update for the part of javascript**

```
addButtonListener($("#store > .r > .a"), function(event, target){
        $("#some_content").css("display", "none");
        $("#other_content").css("display", "block");
        $(".r > .b > .a > img").attr("src" , "store_btn_on.png");
        $(".r > .b > .b > img, .r > .b > .c > img").attr("src" , "store_btn_off.png");
});

function addButtonListener(targets, job){
    if ("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement){
        targets.each(function(){
            $(this)[0].addEventListener('touchstart', function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                $(this).attr({ "x": event.targetTouches[0].clientX, "diffX": 0, "y": event.targetTouches[0].clientY, "diffY": 0 });
                $(this).addClass("on");
            }, false);
            $(this)[0].addEventListener('touchmove', function(event){
                $(this).attr({
                    "diffX": Math.abs(event.targetTouches[0].clientX - $(this).attr("x")),
                    "diffY": Math.abs(event.targetTouches[0].clientY - $(this).attr("y"))
                });
            }, false);
            $(this)[0].addEventListener("touchend", function(event){
                $(this).removeClass("on");
                if ($(this).attr("diffX") < 5 && $(this).attr("diffY") < 5){ $(job(event, $(this))); }
            }, false);
        });
    }
    else {
        targets.each(function(){
            $(this).mousedown(function(event){ event.preventDefault(); $(this).addClass("on"); });
            $(this).mouseup(function(event){ event.preventDefault(); if ($(this).hasClass("on")){ $(job(event, $(this))); } $(this).removeClass("on"); });
            $(this).hover(function(event){ $(this).removeClass("on"); });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't HTML: `class="src="store_btn_on.png"`. I think something is missing from your example.

Comment: @CharlesYeung: Your code looks really weird. Is this your first time coding HTML?

Comment: @nhahtdh: Updated again, sorry for that

Comment: Those images look pretty simple. Why not use [`linear-gradient`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-images/#linear-gradients) (and its vendor-prefixed forms) and fall back to a solid color for incompatible browsers?

Comment: `$(this)[0]` is redundant; just use `this`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure about the sensitivity of your button on mobile devices (you haven't shown any of your code for handling click events), but I think it is better to write your HTML like this:

```
<div class="r">
    <div class="button on">
        <span>Shatin</span>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
        <span>Bay</span>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
        <span>Bay</span>                           
    </div>
</div>
```

Then use CSS in your stylesheet:

```
.button {
    background: url(http://domain.com/images/store_btn_off.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    /* Additional button styles */
}

.button.on {
    background: url(http://domain.com/images/store_btn_on.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}

.button span {
    color: #FFF;
    margin: auto;
}
```

This makes it easy to dynamically turn a button on or off just by adding or removing the on class.

Although not necessary, you may also be interested in looking at CSS3 gradients to create simple gradient background images like that, and then degrade nicely to an image in browsers without any gradient support.

The class names "r" and "b" are not very descriptive. Unless some HTML/CSS minifier put those there and you have proper names in your development code, I would consider giving your classes more descriptive names as well.

Comment: Should I add `width` and `height` in css for the button image?

Comment: @CharlesYeung Probably, yes. You may also want to make different versions like `.button.small` and `.button.large`. Then in your HTML you can just use `class="small button"` or `class="button"` or `class="large button"`

Comment: your first sentence pretty much says it: this solution is bad if you want compatibility with mobile browsers - especially older ones. symbian for instance wont snap to these "buttons" which makes it hard to click on them